# I have loot in my Clan Castle and I want to upgade it. What will become of the loot?

Tags: clash-of-clans

My Dark Elixir storage is full, so I cannot empty the Clan Castle of loot before I upgrade it.

Will I lose the loot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, any current loot in the clan castle will not be lost. The clan castle acts just like a storage, in the sense that if you upgrade a storage, you won't lose any loot.

The clan castle unlike barracks, spell factories, traps and defensive buildings still works when being upgraded.

Comment: ok, thank you! I knew it remains usable but I wasn't certain about the loot thing since I always collected the loot until now. Thanks again.

Comment: @stus Don't forget to mark the answer as correct, so that future visitors will know it is correct.

Comment: indeed I just started upgrading and the loot remained in the CC - it is 100% functional as if it's not upgrading!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure about that.Especially now,people can still raid your CC and DE storage and take a lot of your Dark away.If your CC gets destroyed,some of the loot will be as well.